# How to install latex on Redhat 6?

Tags: installing

I am working on latex and R. Now i need to deploy my application on server for that i need to install on RHEL 6. Where can i find complete source. I cannot install online since my server is not connected to Internet.

Comment: you can download an iso of texlive [here](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-iso.html). So you should be able to install it without internet acces. I have no experience with R on linux so I cant help you there.

Comment: That software is just 2.5 MB. I think it needs Internet connection for installation.

Comment: I have downloaded install-tl-unx.tar.g from the above link but getting following error message. Error Message: cannot contact mirror.ctan.org, returning a backbone server!
Loading http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb
./install-tl: Could not load TeX Live Database from http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet, goodbye.
Please select a different mirror! Press Enter to continue.

Comment: no you should download their "huge" iso from the site so you can burn a dvd and (probably) install without internet access [here](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-iso.html)

Comment: btw no need to burn it on a dvd just need to transport it to your server and mount the iso.The size is 2.3G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded and mounted ISO file. Now it is done.